# Incomplete Orders

Tags: cartthrob

Using Cartthrob I have a checkout order form where I would like to send a notification email to an administrator if the user enters their details but leaves the page before completing the order. This would be first step during checkout so I can capture basic details before they proceed to selecting payment terms and completing checkout. I have looked at Postmaster and can't seem to figure how to make it work in my circumstance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectiveHTML wrote up all the variables you would need for Abandon Cart emails in the [PostMaster documentation](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/notifications/cartthrob-abandoned-cart). PostMaster is really powerful and can do a lot of things so I recommend that you use the [Getting Started guide](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/getting-started) to get to terms with all the terminology.

Comment: Thanks, I have created the notification but when I ping the URL it does not send a mail. Seems like a software issue as couple others also struggling with this.